# Does function returned in onclick has html element?

Tags: javascript

Well, as in the title.

For example, I have something like that:

```
<input type="submit" value="some value" onclick="return function name()" />
<script>
function name(){
var htmlElement = //i want to get here clicked input's value
return false;
}
</script>
```

Is there anyway to do this? Does this function includes 'this' or anything? I don't want to use jQuery here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reference to the calling element (this) isn't included by default. You'd call it like:

```
<input type="submit" value="some value" onclick="return name(this)" />
```

and then change your function to use that parameter:

```
function name(elem){
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I aprreciate. :)